# replace partition for a table in KDB

Tags: kdb

I have a KDB table which is splayed and partitioned:

```
db/2018.10.01/mydata/...columns
db/2018.10.02/mydata/...columns
db/2018.10.03/mydata/...columns
```

I want to replace partition db/2018.10.02/mydata/ with the one containing updated values, but dont know how to do it.

I have tried this:

```
`:D:/db/2018.10.02/mydata/ set delete date from mydata
```

Getting this error:

```
(Roundtrip: 000ms)
ERROR: 'par 
(trying to update a physically partitioned table)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The par error is coming from the delete query. `delete date from mydata` as you must be trying to operate on the partitioned table itself. You should load in the data you need from 2018.10.02, update and save down.

Splayed tables with sym columns also need to be enumerated with .Q.en and any attributes may need reapplied after the update such as the parted attribute on a sym column.

Something like this:

```
// load and update data
res:delete date from select from mydata where date = 2018.10.02;
res:update {your updates} from res;

// apply attribute if needed
res:@[res;first exec c from meta[mydata] where a = `p;`p#];

// save down
// assuming the hdb root / sym file is in `:D:/db
`:D:/db/2018.10.02/mydata/ set .Q.en[`:D:/db;res];
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qen-enumerate-varchar-cols

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/set-attribute/

https://code.kx.com/q/kb/splayed-tables/#enumerating-symbol-columns